# Consolidating jQuery listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

Lately I've been working on a project that requires me to make numerous AJAX calls to a Symfony backend. Since each AJAX call is made to a different URI, I've ended up with a script that's really long, but with numerous .on('event', function(){...}) code blocks, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //AJAX call
```

This is basically duplicated over and over again, but because of slight variations in the selector and the type of data to be received, I keep writing this same block of code over and over again.

I've been thinking of using a builder pattern (is it even possible in JS?) to trim the code. I'm not very good at javascript, so any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
/**
 * AJAX prototype
 *
 * @param options
 * @constructor
 */

//set TestProtObj properties in the constructor
var AjaxProt = function (options) {
    this.ajaxCallType = options.ajaxCallType;
    this.targetEl = options.targetEl;
    this.event = options.event;
    this.method = options.method;
    this.htmlFactory = options.htmlFactory;
};

//add methods to the object prototype
AjaxProt.prototype = {

    init: function () {
        var targetEl = this.targetEl;
        targetEl.on(this.event, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.ajaxCall();
        })
    },

    modalCallback: function(successData) {
        var modal = this.htmlFactory.createHtml({
            title: 'Bet: Detailed View',
            id: '#bet-detailed-model',
            htmlType: 'modal'
        });

        if (successData.success = true) {
            $('#content').prepend(modal);
            $('#bet-detailed-model').modal({show:
                true
            });
        } else {
            $('#content').prepend(modal);
            $('#bet-detailed-model').modal({
                show: true
            });
            $('.modal-body').append(alert);
        }
    },

    ajaxCall: function() {
        var url = this.targetEl.attr('href'),
            method = this.method,
            ajaxCallType = this.ajaxCallType;

        switch (ajaxCallType) {
            case 'modalGet':
                var callback = this.modalCallback();
                break;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            success: function(data) {
                callback(data)
            }
        });
    }
};

//initialize client code
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize new AjaxPro
    var AjaxBetDetailed = new AjaxProt ({
        ajaxCallType: 'modalGet',
        targetEl: $('.ajax-ticket-view'),
        event: 'click',
        method: 'GET',
        htmlFactory: new HtmlFactory()
    });

    //initialize concrete object
    AjaxBetDetailed.init();
});
```

Unfortunately, it appears that my event handler is not binding, such that e.preventDefault is not working - all it does is follow the link. I'm really not used to writing classes in this way, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 2:

I've also written a proof of concept class in jsfiddle that tries to replicate the behaviour I want to achieve. It is also failing to bind the event handler - so that must be the problem. I don't seem to be able to solve it.

JSFiddle: [Click Me Please!](https://jsfiddle.net/p9fjamz3/2/)

Comment: Could you show us an entire block (or two) to better demonstrate the differences between them?

Comment: Need to see a pattern in order to provide any suggestions

Comment: Ok guys, I finally got of my lazy ass to code this pattern because I was getting too lazy to keep copy/pasting my lousy spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse the same function with your "slight variations" as parameters:

```
function registerClick(className, url, param) {
   $('.' + className).on('click', function(e) {
     // Ajax call using url and param, for instance
   });
}
```

And then use it:

```
registerClick('class', '/api/foo', 'bar');
registerClick('toto', '/api/foo', 'buzz');
```

That's not specific to JS but any kind of programming/scripting language: put all reusable code into a function (or an object if you want it oriented object, or a prototype if you want it oriented prototype, etc, but the idea is the same).